# Computing Combinations

Tags: algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I am facing difficulty in coming up with a solution for the problem given below:

We are given n boxes each having a weight ( it means each ball in box B_i have weight C_i),

Each box contain some balls specifically 
{b1,b2,b3...,b_n} (b_i is the count of balls in Box B_i).

we have to choose m balls out of it such that sum of the weights of m chosen balls be less than a given number T.

How many ways to do it?

Comment: Hint: Suppose you build a solution by choosing k balls in order, with k at least 1. Suppose the first box you chose was i. Then the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ..., kth balls must be a solution to a slight variation of the same problem, where the weight constraint is now T - C_i (instead of T), and b_i is one less than the original b_i.

Comment: @j_random_hacker i got the recursive approach but facing difficulty in implementing it with using Dp, can you explain the Dp approach of yours.

Comment: Whenever you find a recursion that (a) solves the problem using only *optimal* solutions to the subproblems and (b) involves solving some subproblems more than once, you can use top-down DP (also called memoisation): whenever the function is called, check whether that subproblem has been solved before, and if so, simply return the answer right away.  If not (i.e. if this is the first time this subproblem has been seen), solve the subproblem and store its result in the DP matrix (or other data structure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's have a look on a similar problem:

The similar problem is: you are looking to *maximize the sum* (such that it is still smaller then T), you are facing a variation of [subset-sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard). The variation with a constant number of items is discussed in this thread: [Sum-subset with a fixed subset size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8916539/572670).

An alternative way to look at the problem is with a 2-dimensional [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), where weight = cost, and an extra dimension for number of elements. This concept is discussed in this thread: [What's the fastest way to solve knapsack prob with two properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13404173/572670)

Now, look at your problem: Finding the number of possible ways to achieve a sum which is smaller/equal T is still **NP-Hard**.

Assume you had a polynomial algorithm to do it, let it be `A`.

Running `A(T)` and `A(T-1)` will give you two numbers, if `A(T) > A(T-1)`, the answer to the subset sum problem would have been `true` - otherwise it is `false`, so given a polynomial solution to this problem, we could prove P=NP.

Comment: its not an optimization prolem, i need to compute the number of possible ways to do so.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja: Oh, misunderstood you at first. I need to think for a minute, but I think it is still NP-Hard, since to find if there is *any* way to do it and get *exactly* to `T` is NP-Hard..

Comment: not exactly to T, i just need the cases where sum of b_i is less than T

Comment: @amit NP-hard means nothing. It's just the worst-case. For small inputs, an algorithm based on dynamic programming is still feasible.

Comment: @XiaoJia: I disagree. NP-Hard means a LOT - specifically, it means there is no known polynomial solution. DP solution (such as suggested for the variation of knapsack) are *pseudo polynomial*, which means that for input of 30 bits, you still are going to have 2^30 ~= 1 Billion possibilities for `k`, and the solution quickly becomes infeasible. Note that I never claimed it cannot be done, it is cannot be done *efficiently* (in the literature *efficiently* = *polynomially*) unless P=NP.

Comment: @amit I totally agree with you. But I was saying for small inputs. Life is hard :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by using dynamic programming techniques.

Let `f[i][j][k]` denote the number of ways to choose `j` balls from `B_1` to `B_i` with sum of weights to be **exactly** `k`. The answer you want to get is `f[n][m][T]`.

```
Initially, let f[i][j][k] = 1 for all i,j,k
for i = 1 to n
  for j = 0 to m
    for k = 0 to T
      for x = 0 to min(b_i,j)  # choose x balls from B_i
        y = x * C_i
        if y <= k
          f[i][j][k] = f[i][j][k] * f[i-1][j-x][k-y] * Comb(b_i,x)
```

`Comb(n,k)` is the number of ways to choose `k` elements from `n` elements.

The time complexity is O(n m T b) where b is the maximum number of balls in a box.

Note that, because of the `T` in the big-O notation, theoretically it is NP-hard. However, in practice, when `T` is relatively small, this algorithm is still feasible.

Comment: i don't want sum to be exactly T, sum may be less than T.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja Then sum up the values of f[n][m][z] where z = 0 to T