# Solving a Knapsack prob with 'min value' constraints on each item

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Every item has three properties

- The size of the item S<sub>i</sub>
- The value of the item V<sub>i</sub>
- The minimum value required to add the item into the knapsack M<sub>i</sub> (<= 10<sup>7</sup>)

The will be atmost 100 items.

We are given the size of the knapsack K (K <= 1000) and the initial value V (which takes no space in the knapsack). 
 An item 'i' can be put into the knapsack if and only if M<sub>i</sub> is less than or equal to V. 
After adding the item in the knapsack V increases by V<sub>i</sub>. 
We have to maximize the number of items (not the value) put into the knapsack of a given size.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404173/whats-the-fastest-way-to-solve-knapsack-prob-with-two-properties) which is similar . But the algorithm described in the answer is cubic time which will not be fast enough for this problem. How do we approach this problem in a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give out an O(n^3) algorithm here. I don't know if this question can be further optimized to O(n^2).

First of all, this question is to maximize the number if items, which is a bit different with other knapsack problems. Meanwhile, it also has a restriction that a single item can only be chosen when the total value of knapsack is larger than its own value. So an obvious inference is, with the same number of items being chosen and fixed total size, the total value should be as large as possible(so that more items can be added to the knapsack).

Notice that the number of items n(<=100) and the size of knapsack K(<=1000) is not very large, let f[i][j] means the maximum value when choose i items with total size j. Initially, all f[i][j] are set to 0 except f[0][0]=V.

Then sort items based on their minimum value required to add. This is a greedy thinking because after sorting, we can go through each item only once.

The DP method looks like follow:

```
for (int k=0;k<n;k++) //iterate items
    for (int i=n;i>=0;i--)
        for (int j=K;j>=0;j--) if (item.M[k]<=f[i][j])
            f[i+1][j+item.S[k]]=max(f[i+1][j+item.S[k]],f[i][j]+item.V[k]);
```

And the final answer(the maximum number of items) is:

```
for (int i=n;i>=0;i--)
    for (int j=0;j<=K;j++)
        if (f[i][j]) return i;
```

Comment: Thanks, in my question by cubic I meant O(N*K*max(Vi)) which might not run under time limit, but your algorithm will run under the time limit easily.